# angular 2 how to get inyected data from controller

Tags: angular

I've this component:

```
<element skillType="tec"></element>
```

I need to get the `skillType` param in my controller, i'm doing it like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'element',
    template: `
    {{skillType}}
  `
})
    export class element {

        @Input() skillType: string;
        console.log(skillType);
    }
```

In the template i get the text `tec`, but in the log i get `undefined`, i also tried with ngOnInit, but still getting the same results.

any thoughts?

thanks in advance!

Comment: what is tec? value or variable?

Comment: @micronyks hi, it's a value

Comment: You mean `tec` string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If **tec** is a **string** then,

```
<element skillType="'tec'"></element>

export class element {

    @Input() skillType: string;

    ngOnInit(){
       console.log(this.skillType);
    }
}
```

If **tec** is an **expression**,

```
<element [skillType]="tec"></element>

export class element {

    @Input() skillType: string;

    ngOnInit(){
       console.log(this.skillType);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this has got something to do with importing your component into the component that you actually use it in and how you are not referring to the class variable using `this`.

For example - to use the element component in, say, upload component you need to import it and then add it to the directives array like so:

```
import { ElementComponent } from '../shared/test.component.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'upload',
  templateUrl: './upload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./upload.component.scss'],
  providers: [UploadService, ThreeService, HelperService, ExampleProductService],
  directives: [LoaderComponent, ProductEditorComponent, ElementComponent]
})
```

I also rewrote your component as my compiler was complaining about the console.log:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'element',
    template: `<p>{{skillType}}</p>`
})
export class ElementComponent {
  @Input() skillType: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.skillType);
  }
}
```